# Kubernetes pod unable to download from npm registry EAI_AGAIN

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-networking

I have a minikube setup where a container needs to access npm registry when starting up. But the pod can not connect to npm registry. I was under the impression that all outgoing connections are open from K8s.

### Log from the pod

`kubectl logs <pod_name>`

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/sequelize-cli failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-14T12_16_23_892Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'sequelize-cli@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install && yarn global add npx
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

### Entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e           # Stop on any error
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:all  # Run migrations
npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all     # Preload initial data
exec "$@"        # Run the command as the main container process
```

### Deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-auth-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: service-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: service-auth
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-auth
        image: REMOVED:1.0.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: SESSION_SECRET
            value: REMOVED
          - name: DB_USER
            value: auth
          - name: DB_PASS
            value: secret
          - name: DB_NAME
            value: users
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: mysql
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerhub-secret
```

### Service-Cluster-Ip.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-auth-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: service-auth
  ports: 
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

If more information is needed, let me know. I am new to k8s.

Comment: Hello @Sisir. How exactly did you got those logs and are they from the Pod or the Container? Could you show the Service configuration that exposes the Pod?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, Thank you! I have added more information on my question.

Comment: Hi again @Sisir. Sorry for the late response. Could you also show the complete log from `/root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-14T12_16_23_892Z-debug.log`?

Answer (score 0):

`reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN` exactly indicates there is a network issue in your env. Since using K8s, I change `dnsPolicy` from `ClusterFirst` to `Default`

For example,

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-red
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-red
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: Default
```

Reference > https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/